# Expectation by integral

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

I am trying to compute the expectation of 
$\mathbb{E}[XY]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent on a third non-negative random variable $Z$.

I can now compute the expectation as follows

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z=z]dF_{Z}(z)$$
I am also familiar with the equivalent representation

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[XY\mathbb{1}_{Z\in[z,z+dz)}]$$

where $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is the indicator function on $A$.
I am now wondering whether I can write this expectation as follows

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[XY\mathbb{1}_{Z=z}]dz$$

I do not want to assume that $Z$ has a density function.
Could anyone tell me if this last representation is correct and perhaps provide a proof even?

Comment: The first identity is correct, the second one is undefined, the third one is wrong. Re the third identity, note that if $P(Z=z)=0$ for every $z$, then the RHS is zero, not E(XY).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. The second identity should be $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[XY\delta(Z-z)dz]$ where $\delta(Z-z)dz$ represents the Dirac Delta function.

Comment: Unfortunately this use of the Dirac function is not mathematically founded (only physicists are able to play with it and get correct results...).

Comment: Ok, another question: How can I split this expectation into covariance and $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z=z]$?

Comment: Another question $\implies$ another post.

Comment: @LeilaHatami You "resurrected" this 2.5 years old post by a completely minor edit. Was it useful?